# Rotating whole body in y-axis

Tags: css, animation

I created a stick figure with `< pre >` tags and I want to rotate the figures whole body in its`Y-Axis`. I try to find out how I can `rotate` the middle of the body in its`Y-axis,` but its always out of place.

Here is how it looks now:

```css
 @keyframes rotate{
0% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
50% {transform:rotate(135deg);}
0% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
 }
 
  @keyframes rotate2{
0% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
50% {transform:rotate(-135deg);}
0% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
 }
 
@keyframes rotate3{
 0% {transform: rotateY(0deg);}
 50% {transform: rotateY(360deg);}
 0% {transform: rotateY(0deg);}
 }

 
pre{
position:absolute;
text-shadow: 10px 10px 3px #DCDCDC;
font-size: 400%;
}


div{
border-bottom: 5px solid magenta;
position:absolute;
width: 160px;
left:200px;
bottom:50px;
/*margin-top: 0px;*/
/*margin-bottom: 0px;*/
}

.head{
 position:absolute;
animation-duration:4s;
animation-name:rotate3;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}




 
.legs{
 position:absolute;
animation-duration:4s;
animation-name:rotate3;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

.leftleg.rightleg{
position:absolute;}
 

 
.stomach{
 position:absolute;
animation-duration:4s;
animation-name:rotate3;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

 
.rightarm{
position:absolute;
transform-origin:top right;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-name:rotate;
animation-duration: 4s;
}

.leftarm{
 position:absolute;
 transform-origin: top left;
 animation-name:rotate2;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-duration: 4s;
}

.arms{
 position:absolute;
animation-duration:4s;
animation-name:rotate3;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
```

```html
<pre>
  <span class="all"><span class="head">o</span>
 <span class="arms"><span class="rightarm">/</span> <span class="stomach">O</span> <span class="leftarm">\</span></span>
 <span class="legs"><span class="rightleg">/</span> <span class="leftleg">\</span></span><span>
 <div></div>
</pre>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n3nbbgcv/

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) You can edit your post instead of commenting it. (Rotating nested spans looks *advanced*.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `transform-origin: left` to `.stomach`

```css
 @keyframes rotate{
0% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
50% {transform:rotate(135deg);}
0% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
 }
 
  @keyframes rotate2{
0% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
50% {transform:rotate(-135deg);}
0% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
 }
 
@keyframes rotate3{
 0% {transform: rotateY(0deg);}
 50% {transform: rotateY(360deg);}
 0% {transform: rotateY(0deg);}
 }

 
pre{
position:absolute;
text-shadow: 10px 10px 3px #DCDCDC;
font-size: 400%;
}


div{
border-bottom: 5px solid magenta;
position:absolute;
width: 160px;
left:200px;
bottom:50px;
/*margin-top: 0px;*/
/*margin-bottom: 0px;*/
}

.head{
 position:absolute;
animation-duration:4s;
animation-name:rotate3;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}




 
.legs{
 position:absolute;
animation-duration:4s;
animation-name:rotate3;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

.leftleg.rightleg{
position:absolute;}
 

 
.stomach{
 position:absolute;
animation-duration:4s;
animation-name:rotate3;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
transform-origin: left;
}

 
.rightarm{
position:absolute;
transform-origin:top right;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-name:rotate;
animation-duration: 4s;
}

.leftarm{
 position:absolute;
 transform-origin: top left;
 animation-name:rotate2;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-duration: 4s;
}

.arms{
 position:absolute;
animation-duration:4s;
animation-name:rotate3;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
```

```html
<pre>
  <span class="all"><span class="head">o</span>
 <span class="arms"><span class="rightarm">/</span> <span class="stomach">O</span> <span class="leftarm">\</span></span>
 <span class="legs"><span class="rightleg">/</span> <span class="leftleg">\</span></span><span>
 <div></div>
</pre>
```

Comment: Weird it works without semicolon, but with semicolon it will not work at all. Now I try to spin this guy like a wheel but he spin always not in the middle, it look hilarious :D jsfiddle.net/Lv0ytxgk

Comment: Thank you, it helped me alot !